# JAXB Issue Array Not Mapping

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Can anyone tell me why the products aren't mapping? (always null) I'm using JAXB for marshaling

XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getAccountProductsResponse xmlns="http://CellucomPosa/">
         <getAccountProductsResult>
            <CellucomPOSA xmlns="">
               <Product>
                  <ProductID>280</ProductID>
                  <ProductName>AT&amp;T $15</ProductName>
                  <Discount>18</Discount>
                  <Price>15.00</Price>
                  <ProdType>PINRTR</ProdType>
               </Product>
               <Product>
                  <ProductID>281</ProductID>
                  <ProductName>AT&amp;T $25</ProductName>
                  <Discount>18</Discount>
                  <Price>25.00</Price>
                  <ProdType>PINRTR</ProdType>
               </Product>
            </CellucomPOSA>
         </getAccountProductsResult>
      </getAccountProductsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my POJO
    package cellucomposa;

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getAccountProductsResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getAccountProductsResponse")
public class GetAccountProductsResponse {

    protected GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult getAccountProductsResult;

    public GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult getGetAccountProductsResult() {
        return getAccountProductsResult;
    }


    public void setGetAccountProductsResult(GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult value) {
        this.getAccountProductsResult = value;
    }



    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "CellucomPOSA"
    })
    public static class GetAccountProductsResult {

        @XmlElement(namespace="")
        protected GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA CellucomPOSA;

        public GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA getCellucomPOSA() {
            return CellucomPOSA;
        }

        public void setCellucomPOSA(
                GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA cellucomPOSA) {
            this.CellucomPOSA = cellucomPOSA;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "Product"
        })
        public static class CellucomPOSA {

            protected GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA.Product[] Product;

            public GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA.Product[] getProduct() {
                return Product;
            }

            public void setProduct(
                    GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA.Product[] product) {
                this.Product = product;
            }

            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            public static class Product {

                @XmlElement(name = "ProductID")
                protected int productID;

                @XmlElement(name = "ProductName")
                protected String ProductName;

                @XmlElement(name = "Discount")
                protected String discount;

                @XmlElement(name = "Price")
                protected String price;

                @XmlElement(name = "ProdType")
                protected String prodType;

                public int getProductID() {
                    return productID;
                }

                public void setProductID(int productID) {
                    this.productID = productID;
                }

                public String getProductName() {
                    return ProductName;
                }

                public void setProductName(String productName) {
                    ProductName = productName;
                }

                public String getDiscount() {
                    return discount;
                }

                public void setDiscount(String discount) {
                    this.discount = discount;
                }

                public String getPrice() {
                    return price;
                }

                public void setPrice(String price) {
                    this.price = price;
                }

                public String getProdType() {
                    return prodType;
                }

                public void setProdType(String prodType) {
                    this.prodType = prodType;
                }                   
            }               
        }    
    }  
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of, any help would be greatly appreciated, is there something missing

Ok after the helpful I comment I figured out what the correct mapping was here is the solution so far, one problem though all ProductIDs aren't mapping anyone have any ideas

```
package cellucomposa;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getAccountProductsResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getAccountProductsResponse")
public class GetAccountProductsResponse {

    protected GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult getAccountProductsResult;

    public GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult getGetAccountProductsResult() {
        return getAccountProductsResult;
    }

    public void setGetAccountProductsResult(GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult value) {
        this.getAccountProductsResult = value;
    }



    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "CellucomPOSA"
    })
    public static class GetAccountProductsResult {

        @XmlElement(namespace="")
        protected GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA CellucomPOSA;

        public GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA getCellucomPOSA() {
            return CellucomPOSA;
        }

        public void setCellucomPOSA(
                GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA cellucomPOSA) {
            this.CellucomPOSA = cellucomPOSA;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "Product"
        })
        public static class CellucomPOSA {

            @XmlElement(namespace="")
            protected List<GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA.Product> Product;

            public List<GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA.Product> getProduct() {
                return Product;
            }

            public void setProduct(
                    List<GetAccountProductsResponse.GetAccountProductsResult.CellucomPOSA.Product> product) {
                this.Product = product;
            }

            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                    "ProductID",
                    "ProductName",
                    "Discount",
                    "Price",
                    "ProdType"
                })
            public static class Product {

                @XmlElement(name="ProductId", namespace="")
                protected int ProductID;

                @XmlElement(name="ProductName", namespace="")
                protected String ProductName;

                @XmlElement(name="Discount", namespace="")
                protected String Discount;

                @XmlElement(name="Price", namespace="")
                protected String Price;

                @XmlElement(name="ProdType", namespace="")
                protected String ProdType;

                public int getProductID() {
                    return ProductID;
                }

                public void setProductID(int productID) {
                    this.ProductID = productID;
                }

                public String getProductName() {
                    return ProductName;
                }

                public void setProductName(String productName) {
                    ProductName = productName;
                }

                public String getDiscount() {
                    return Discount;
                }

                public void setDiscount(String discount) {
                    this.Discount = discount;
                }

                public String getPrice() {
                    return Price;
                }

                public void setPrice(String price) {
                    this.Price = price;
                }

                public String getProdType() {
                    return ProdType;
                }

                public void setProdType(String prodType) {
                    this.ProdType = prodType;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the XML look like when you populate the object model and marshal it to XML?  Then what is the difference between that XML and the XML you are trying to unmarshal?

Comment: Ok I've done what you said, worked great! Figured what was wrong, I'll add what the solution was to get his mapped here in a second. I do have one other question, why isn't "ProductID" mapping? Everything else is when type is int all ProductIDs map to "0" when type is String all ProductIDs map to "null"

Comment: Ok nevermind I figured it out it was the lowercase "d" in my XmlElement annotation, made it uppercase and voila! Thanks so much for the help and also, thanks to your blog too, it has helped out tremendously, @BlaiseDoughan you are the man!!